# Replicate word-style text table as a Power App (see pic)

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-canvas

I'm trying to replicate a word form as a power app for digital submission, and the important info is contained in a table something like this...

The last two columns (comments and grade) are the user input fields. I want it to be formatted so that there is plenty of room for multi-line text in the comments field.

How should I build this? Floating cards? Containers? Horizontal containers nested in vertical ones? Something else?

For what it's worth, this would almost always be completed on a desktop, so it doesn't need to be too responsive to screen resolution. Just has to work reliably!

Thanks!

---

| Number | Criteria Description | Comments | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Experience | bla bla bla | B+ |
| 2 | Skills | bla bla bla | A+ |
| 3 | Teamwork | bla bla bla | A |
| 4 | Skills | bla bla bla | C |
| 5 | Culture & Fit | bla bla bla | B |
| - | Overall | bla bla bla | A+ |

---

Tried with containers, but wasn't able to fit it all in, because the apparent limitation to stacking containers.

Also tried with shapes and floating text input fields, but that seems cumbersome and a poor approach.

I'm sure someone else has a better idea!